# How to color the whole WIDTH behind a header in MS word?

Tags: microsoft-word, colors, background

I am trying to redesign my CV a bit. I would like to add some sort of header with a decent coloured background since I saw a similar design on another CV that I've really liked. However, I didn't find any options to colour the whole width of the document. I found the option to colour the whole background but as the name suggests, this colours the CV as a whole.

Any suggestions? Appreciate any insight. Thank you!

[image: See the header here]

Answer (score 2):

### Apply shading to the Header paragraph style.

That will color from right indent to left indent. You may need to change the paragraph indents as well, perhaps setting a first line indent.

The simple

1. way to do this is to click in one of your Headers to edit it.
2. Then, under the Home Tab, click on the Borders button and go to the bottom of the menu and pick Borders and Shading.
3. A dialog will open, click on the tab at the top for Shading.
4. Pick your Shading color.
5. Pick to apply it to the Paragraph.
6. OK your way out of that dialog and your header will be shaded.

To apply this to the Header *style* you would:

1. While in the header with the shading launch the [Styles Pane](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/ManageStyles.htm#StylesPane). You can do that with the keyboard shortcut **Ctrl+Shift+Alt+S**.
2. Right-Click on the Header style in that pane.
3. Pick Update Style to match formatting.

### You could also place a rectangle with the color in your header and place it behind text.

You would go into the Header for editing then go to the Insert Tab and insert a Shape - a rectangle. Color it. Set it to be behind text. Close the header.

Comment: Explaining how to do your recommendations would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use Publisher instead of Word.

Word is designed to mostly work within the limits of normal printers, many of which cannot print to the edge of the page.

With digital documents this is less necessary, and there are ways to coax Word into giving you this layout ([see Charles Kenyon's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1648391/74026)) but Word is still mostly about page layout.

Publisher, on the other hand, is more flexible about how content can be arranged on a page and so makes it easier to apply elements that run the full width of a page or outside a typical printer's limits, if that's what you want.